# swift Parse JSON Fail

Tags: json, swift, codable

I confirm that the content is not wrong. When I only parse one time, it is the same as nil.

```
struct MyFriend: Codable {

var id: String
var friendName: String
var latitude: String
var longitude: String
var lastUpdateDateTime: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "id"
    case friendName = "friendName"
    case latitude = "lat"
    case longitude = "lon"
    case lastUpdateDateTime = "lastUpdateDateTime"
}

}
```

This is my parsing process

```
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: targetURL) { (data, respnse, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print("Donwnload Fail: \(error)")
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            print("Data is nil")
            return
        }

        // Parse JSON from data
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let results = try? decoder.decode([MyFriend].self, from: data)

        if let results = results {
            print("results: \(results)")
        } else {
            // Pares Fail
            print("Pares Fail")
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

There is no error in the URL. I don't know why parse is always Pares Fail.

Comment: post the json , also insert do this **do {  let results = try decoder.decode([MyFriend].self, from: data) } catch { print (error) }**

Comment: Please post the JSON. The question cannot be answered without knowing the JSON. And don't `try?` JSON decoding. **`Catch`** the error and print it rather than a meaningless literal string. And the second `guard` is redundant. If `error` is `nil`, `data` is guaranteed to be not `nil` and vice versa

Comment: Your code is not wrong. If you're getting a parse failure it is almost certainly because you're expecting an array of MyFriend objects back but actually getting a dictionary in the JSON. As others have said, you need to post the JSON to confirm this.

Comment: Can you show any errors which are logged?

Comment: Try @Sh_Khan suggestion. do catch will show the exact error in parsing the keys. I will suggest using `error.description` for more parsing error detail

Comment: @Pawan If you do `print(error)`, it implicitly calls `error.description`.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks. i did not notice that yet.